# why the result of window.getSelection.toString becomes ellipsis,when seleced text a little long?

Tags: monaco-editor, getselection

when i use monaco-editor in my program, and when i select some long codes in the editor,the result of window.getSelection.toString becomes ellipsis,like "xxxxxx ... xxxxx",while it goes normal as relatively short codes are selected.

are there any answer?

Comment: Are you sure this not just how your console displays it? Does `window.getSelection.toString().length` seem legit?

Comment: window.getSelection().toString().length is also incorrect,when selected text is long,some text of the window.getSelection() above seems to be transformed to ellipsis

Comment: Would help to have an [mre]

Comment: the screen recording example is in the answer below

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.